# Python/BeautifulSoup - HTML Parsing Multiple Tags and Classes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse through a nested set of HTML script.

HTML Script:

```
<div class="example one">
   <ol class="example two">
      <li class="example three">
```

**My goal**: scrape the text under the "li class"
**The issue:** li class appears several times in this HTML script, and some of the results I don't want to scrape. I want to scrape this text using BeautifulSoup, referencing multiple tags and multiple classes.

What I'm using right now:

```
all_batters = soupList.find_all(re.compile('div'|'li'), {'class':re.compile('example one'|'example three')})
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  soupList is correct then join the compound classes and add in a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

```
[i.text for i in soupList.select(".example.one .example.three")]
```

If you need example two in there then add it in between the existing class selectors above.

Depending on the rest of the html you may be able to use just one of the compound classes:

```
[i.text for i in soupList.select(".one .three")]
```